# How to explicitly instantiate class with default template arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, explicit-instantiation

I have a class with type and non-type(default) template parameters. The non-type parameters could be combined, and can be instantiated in the following ways:

```
TNT<int> v;
TNT<double, X, Y> v2;
TNT<float, X | X1, Y1> v3;
TNT<int, X | X1, Y | Y1, Z | Z1 | Z2, W> v4;
```

The class `TNT` has a type parameter, and rest are default. What is the correct way to explicitly instantiate such a class in the cpp file? Since the non-type parameters could be combined, a lot of combinations are possible.

Comment: I don't quite get it. If they have default values then the default values are used. If the values are combined they're not default anymore, are they?

Comment: For eg.,for  the first example -- `TNT<int> v`, the default values for non-types shall be used. But, for the second example, for the second and third parameter, the user passes the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the thing you're not getting is this. `TNT<int, 5>` is a *completely different type* from `TNT<int, 4>`. They are as different from each other as `vector<int>` is from `vector<float>`.

As such, you cannot instantiate all possible non-type parameters. If you instantiate `TNT<int>` then you are instantiating the *specific* template that uses the default parameters. If your default params were 1, 2, 3, then `TNT<int>` would be equivalent to `TNT<int, 1, 2, 3>`.

But that's it. There is no syntax that will instantiate a template for every possible combination of parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about *explicit instantiation* in its usual sense, then I presume your question is about avoiding linking errors when you define template class implementation in a cpp file rather than a header file.

If that is the case, then usual explicit instantiation rules apply, with this syntax:

```
template class TNT<int>;
template class TNT<float, 1.0, 2.0>;
//etc
```

You will need to write as many of these as the combinations used elsewhere require.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. But, as @Nicol Bolas says - `There is no syntax that will instantiate a template for every possible combination of parameter values.`

Comment: No, indeed there isn't. As I said you will need to explicitly write as many of these as you require.